# Groovy:unexpected token: connection @ line 10

Tags: groovy

I am trying to change the status of Channel using groovy script.
For that I need to execute URL and my channel status will be changed.

However, after writing code eclipse showing error at Line Connection.
I am new to groovy please help to fix this issue.

Code -

```
class startChannel {


    def url = new URL("http://XXXXXX&action=**STOP**")
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
    // connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
    connection.connect()
    if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201) {
        def returnMessage = connection.content
    } 
}
```

Error -

```
1. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:expecting EOF, found 'if' @ line 11, column 2.   startChannel.groovy /GroovyTest/src line 11 Java Problem
2. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:unexpected token: connection @ line 10, column 2.    startChannel.groovy /GroovyTest/src line 10 Java Problem
3. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:unexpected token: connection @ line 8, column 2. startChannel.groovy /GroovyTest/src line 8  Java Problem
4. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:unexpected token: if @ line 11, column 2.    startChannel.groovy /GroovyTest/src line 11 Java Problem
```

BR,
Rashmi

Comment: I don't know how did you miss this method `public static void main()`. But you said you are new to groovy ... ! So you don't need to create class

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class. just use the main steps like you said.

```
def url = new URL("http://XXXXXX&action=**STOP**")
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
// connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.connect()
if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201) {
    def returnMessage = connection.content
}
```

I suggest you to study the basics of groovy in http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html.

Comment: Thanks Bhanuchander_U; how do i give id and password to execute this url?

Comment: @RashmiJoshi Please try to ask a focused question, you can learn here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As a newbie, It is really common to ask various questions from the origin question. So no probs. I suggest you to view well asked and related questions.

Comment: @RashmiJoshi If you find this answer helpful, you can upvote and accept the answer. Learn here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers